# what happens if two different sessions are active in one browser?

Tags: php, session-state

what happens if two different application opened at the same-time in one browser and both are using sessions? is other application is able access session variables of other application? if so how to solve this problem. may be this question look meaningless but it is hunting from so many days !

Comment: The last received session cookie will prevail. Both will access the same session data. (Btw, it's possible to have more than one session, just requires a custom handler and distinct ids then.)

Answer (score 2):

Sessions are normally handled by storing a session ID in a cookie which is associated with a given hostname (although can be shared across multiple hostnames which are on the same domain). Cookies can also be limited to subdirectories.

The session data is stored on the server.

If the two applications were running on the same server, on the same domain name, then the possibility is there for them to share data through a shared session store.

Comment: what if they don't run on same server ? is still one application can access other applications session variables?

Comment: It all depends on where the session information is stored. E.g. if you store them in file system (default choice), applications that have access to that directory/files will be able to get session information.

Comment: … so if the session data is stored in the file system, then an application running on a different file system won't have access to it unless it has access to the other server's file system (e.g. if it was shared via NFS).

Comment: am still little confused there for ex: if i logged in to both gmail and facebook at the same is gmail can access facebook session variables if gmail know the variable name ?

Comment: No. They don't share a domain name. They don't share a server. And they are not friendly enough to share the filesystems of their servers with each other over a network.

Comment: is session_id or session_name any useful if both applications run on same server ? i don't know how to exactly use them so i mentioned